# What are the e and L characters I saw in this script, and how do I access them?

Tags: ti-basic

I am following a tutorial using TI-BASIC and there are some characters I don't understand. Here is what it says;

```
For(A,1,ᴇ2
```

I am very confused about the ᴇ2 character, and how to access it. This goes for the L character too, as seen below;

```
ʟA(1)+(K=26)-(K=24)+.1((K=34)-(K=25
```

The ʟA character is the issue causer here. If anyone can let me know what the ᴇ2 and ʟA characters mean, and how I could access them, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The L character stands for List. If you do not know how lists (or arrays) work, check out [this link](https://tibasic.fandom.com/wiki/List). You can access them with "STAT" then "ENTER'

E is "exponent". E is followed by a second number, denoting how many times it is multiplied by ten. For example, you can type in `2x10^2` or you can enter `2ᴇ2`. Both will result in 200. Accessing ᴇ is saved in catalog (2nd+0), but it is easier just to type in `x10^n` instead.